# How to do Stack Swapping in c# or Java

Tags: java, algorithm, c#-4.0, data-structures, stack

I wanted to swap two stacks that means basically the content of the stacks.
How would I be able to do that in C# or Java or C

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? This is not just `Stack h = a; a = b; b = h`, right?

Comment: @Thilo :I don't think it will do the magic.Actually the content of stack needs to be swapped.Correct me if i m wrong..

Comment: Explain why the content of the stack needs to be swapped. Swapping references will have the same effect, and much cheaper.

Comment: @Thilo:Sorry , I forgot to mention C language in my question and i wanted a general algo for applicable for all language and that's why confusion was there ..

Answer (score 6):

Can you just swap the references? I.e. given a stack s1 and s2:

```
Stack<T> temp = s2;
s2 = s1;
s1 = temp;
```

The easiest way to switch the content of the stacks is probably using another stack:

```
int secondSize = s1.size();

while(!s1.isEmpty()){

    holdStack.push(s1.pop());
}
while(!s2.isEmpty()){
    holdStack.push(s2.pop());
}

for(int i = 0; i < secondSize; i++){
    s1.push(holdStack.pop());
}
while(!holdStack.isEmpty()){
    s2.push(holdStack.pop());
}
```

Comment: I don't think your first approach will do the magic and in your second approach you are try to move all content from one stack to another stack, is there any other way.. and by the way in your second approach queue will not do you need another stack , if you use queue your content will be reversed in the stack.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "magic," but I do think in most cases the first solution will work. Please explain why it would not. I have updated the answer so that the second solution maintains order.

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to mention C language in my question and i wanted a general algo for applicable for all language